# Wreorder wrong order on same variable

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

I'm getting an unusual compiler warning like this.

```
warning: '{anonymous}::edge_creator_DDR::edges_' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
map< otg_DDR::edge, otg_DDR::EDGE_TYPE > & edges_;
```

The edge_creator_DDR is a structure and there is no inheritance. The definition  of edges_ is,

```
map< otg_DDR::edge, otg_DDR::EDGE_TYPE > & edges_;
```

`edge_creator_DDR::edges_` and
`map< otg_DDR::edge, otg_DDR::EDGE_TYPE > & edges_`
are the same. Why the compiler gives such a warning?

Comment: I think you should post the whole class definition and the constructor that gives this warning.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an initializer list that initializes `edges_`?

The warning is saying that the initializer list isn't in the same order as the actual initalizations will occur (basically, the order that the members are declared in the class/struct).  This usually isn't a problem, but there are times when the order of initalization matters, and when the init list doesn't match it can mislead readers of the code.

From [the GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options):

> -Wreorder (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
>
> Warn when the order of member initializers given in the code does not
>   match the order in which they must be executed. For instance:
>
> ```
>           struct A {
>             int i;
>             int j;
>             A(): j (0), i (1) { }
>           };
> ```
>
> The compiler rearranges the member initializers for i and j to match
>   the declaration order of the members, emitting a warning to that
>   effect. This warning is enabled by -Wall.

Here is the output I get from g++ when compiling the example from the docs:

```
C:\so-test\test.cpp: In constructor 'A::A()':
C:\so-test\test.cpp:3:17: warning: 'A::j' will be initialized after [-Wreorder]
             int j;
                 ^
C:\so-test\test.cpp:2:17: warning:   'int A::i' [-Wreorder]
             int i;
                 ^
C:\so-test\test.cpp:4:13: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
             A(): j (0), i (1) { }
             ^
```

Comment: Michael: Yes I have an initializing list that initialize edges_. In your example, the i and j are different variables. But in my case, `edge_creator_DDR::edges_` and `map< otg_DDR::edge, otg_DDR::EDGE_TYPE > & edges_` are the same. Normally there has to be 2 different variables in this warnings.
BTW thnx 4 answering.

Comment: @Lahiru: If you need more help, I think you might need to copy/paste all of the relevant lines of output from the compile step and/or post the `edge_creator_DDR` declaration (a minimal compilable repro case might be good).